# SQL Conditional Join (with/without parameter) in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm working with a Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2005. Is it possible to use a join if only the parameter is not null ? Below is an example of the query :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPSample]
@gender varchar(20) = null
@username varchar(20) = null
AS

SELECT
per.firstName,
per.lastName,
per.gender

FROM person per
INNER JOIN account ac on ac.idPerson = per.idPerson

WHERE (
gender = @gender
AND (@username is null or (@username is not null and @username = acc.username))
```

How to make the `INNER JOIN` only works if the `@username` is not null ? What is the best approach to get the expected result ?

Comment: @Sukanya which part that's not clear for you ?

Comment: What actually you wanted to know that was not clear..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPSample]
@gender varchar(20) = null
@username varchar(20) = null
AS

SELECT
per.firstName,
per.lastName,
per.gender

FROM person per
LEFT JOIN account ac 
ON     @username is not null 
   AND @username = ac.username 
   AND ac.idPerson = per.idPerson

WHERE --(
gender = @gender
--AND (@username is null or (@username is not null and @username = acc.username))
```

although not the cleanest, but it works

Comment: I tried that just now, but the query didn't return any rows when I tried to pass a NULL value in the @username when it should be returning a several rows.

Comment: @Andha i think you're talking about left join? and leave the fields of `account` empty if `@username` is null?